# Trouble checking the date range in PHP

Tags: php, symfony

Well, as the title suggests, there is a weird problem in date range checking in my code. Here it is:

First, the AJAX query comes to `ReceiptQueryController.php`, it checks for the request and **Checks if the given date is between a range**.

```
    /**
     * @Route("/querysearch", name="ReceiptQuerySearch")
     */
    public function querySearchAction()
    {
        $request = $this->container->get('request');
        $fromDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->request->get('fd')));
        $toDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->request->get('td')));

        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AdminStoreReceiptReceiptBundle:Receipt');
        $em_product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AdminStoreProductProductBundle:Product');

        $receiptList = array();

        foreach ($em->findAll() as $entity) {
            if ($this->check_in_range($fromDate, $toDate, $entity->getDate())) {
                $receiptDetail = array();
                $receiptDetail['date'] = $entity->getDate()->format('Y/m/d');
                $receiptDetail['time'] = $entity->getTime()->format('H:i');

                $strRes = "";
                $totalPrice = 0;
                $totalPPrice = 0;
                foreach ($entity->getObjects() as $obj) {
                    $product = $em_product->findOneBy(array('barCode' => $obj));
                    $strRes .= $product->getName() . "<span class='pull-right'>خ: " . $product->getPurchasePrice() . ", ف: " . $product->getSalesPrice() . "</span><br>";
                    $totalPrice += $product->getSalesPrice();
                    $totalPPrice += $product->getPurchasePrice();
                }

                $receiptDetail['objects'] = $strRes;
                $receiptDetail['totalReceiptPrice'] = $totalPrice;
                $receiptDetail['totalReceiptPPrice'] = $totalPPrice;
                $receiptList[] = $receiptDetail;
            }
        }

        if (sizeof($receiptList) == 0){
            $receiptList[] = "No Result!";
        }

        $response->setContent(json_encode($receiptList));
        return $response;
    }

}
```

then, **`$this->check_in_range($fromDate, $toDate, $entity->getDate())`** function doesn't seem to work properly as expected!

```
function check_in_range($fromDate, $toDate, $userDate)
    {
        $sDate = date('Y-m-d', $fromDate);
        $eDate = date('Y-m-d', $toDate);
        $uDate = date('Y-m-d', $userDate);

        return (($uDate >= $sDate) && ($uDate <= $eDate));
    }
```

No answers after almost 2 days!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method, $userdate is an Object. You can't pass it as 2nd argument of `date` function.

Try with `format`:

```
function check_in_range($fromDate, $toDate, $userDate)
{
    $sDate = date('Y-m-d', $fromDate);
    $eDate = date('Y-m-d', $toDate);
    $uDate = $userDate->format('Y-m-d');

    return (($uDate >= $sDate) && ($uDate <= $eDate));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment rather than an answer but there is code that would be relatively unreadable in the comments section.

You should move your date check to inside your repository call rather than loading everything into memory as that could become unmanageable as your app grows.

To get all of the receipts for a time span you could use...

```
// Get the repository
$receiptRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AdminStoreReceiptReceiptBundle:Receipt');
// Create a query builder using "r"as the alias for the table
$receiptQueryBuilder = $receiptRepo->createQueryBuilder('r');

// Find all receipts where r.date >= $fromDate && r.date <= $toDate
$receiptList = $receiptQB
    ->where($receiptQueryBuilder->expr()->between('r.date', ':from', ':to'))
    ->setParameter('from', $fromDate)
    ->setParameter('to', $toDate)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResults();
```

This should give you all receipts equal or greater than `$fromDate` and equal or less than `$toDate`.

It would then make sense to move that call into a custom repository so you could use it anywhere like `$receiptList = $receiptRepository->findAllBetweenDates($fromDate, $toDate)`.